# "Sudo: Must Be Setuid Root" error after login to diskless client

Tags: 12.04, server, nfs, pxe

I'm working on diskless linux clusters. I followed instructions as described [here](http://www.serenux.com/2011/04/howto-create-a-diskless-workstation-that-boots-from-pxe-using-ubuntu/comment-page-2/#comment-72360). I did these steps:

```
1- Installed a pxe server on server pc.
2- Installed ubuntu to a client pc.
3- Configured and installed all programs I need on client pc.
4- Copied all OS files(on client pc) to NFS share point.
5- Booted diskless pc via pxe server.
```

It works. But after login to my account, I got this error message : "Sudo: Must Be Setuid Root". So I can't use `/usr/bin/sudo`. How can I fix this? Do I need to change some files on OS files which I copied to PXE server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I have copied the OS files from client pc to server pc. I changed the permissions (`chmod 777 -R /pathToOsFiles`) on these files on server. Then I got this  error message (`Sudo: Must Be Setuid Root`) on diskless pc. I couldn't fix it. I used every options (755, 744 ...) but nothing changed.

Everything works correctly after copied OS files from client pc to server pc again. But this time I didn't change permissions. If someone faces same problem, I can say that don't touch permissions on server after copy the OS files.

One more thing: User names can be different on client pc and server pc but SUID must be same on both. Otherwise you will see same error message.

Comment: Please do not evere change the rights to 777! *Ever!* You should never change the rights for other to write, unless you really know what you doing.

*About the rights*. In NFS the rights for `root` on the remote machine is usually maped to `nobody` on your server. Thats because the server can't really know who the user are on the client (could be any progam).This has been changed in later versions of NFS (NFS v4 I think). You can set the server to allow root, but you shold not.
In NFS v4, the server and client can map user names between each other. If not, it uses the UID and GID as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicated that the /usr/bin/sudo file doesn't have the setuid attribute set. The setuid attribute means that when you execute as if you were the user that owns the file. So, sudo must be owned by root and have this set or it is not able to allow you gain root privileges. You can set this attribute by running `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo` while running as root. You may also need to change the owner to root (`chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo`).

Comment: It might be that NFS file systems are not shared to the client in a way to allow root access to files in them. Read the manual for more information. Mind security though, as there are a reason to have that. Anyone can mount the NFS volumes and be root on their own machines.

Comment: Yes, if the nfs server uses "root_squash" (which is the default) in etc/exports, the root user on the client becomes "nobody" on the server. You can disable this by setting "no_root_squash", but as @Anders mentioned, this is not good for security. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/exports.5.html