# Can't login to root using `sudo su`

Tags: 12.04

While using `sudo su` I am getting this error:

```
sgr@sgr-VirtualBox:~$ sudo su
sudo: must be setuid root
```

I cannot log in to root? Why/How to fix it?

Comment: srg@srg-VirtualBox:/$ chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chown: changing ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo': Operation not permitted  ....i followed this link(  http://askubuntu.com/questions/431959/sudo-must-be-setuid-root-error-after-login-to-diskless-client  ) “Sudo: Must Be Setuid Root” error after login to diskless client.thank you

Comment: Clearly you haven't followed the steps.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is someone messed with `/usr/bin/sudo` permissions. They should be something like :

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 155008 Mar 12 17:27 /usr/bin/sudo
```

but for some reason, yours are likely (note the 's' vs 'x') :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 155008 Mar 12 17:27 /usr/bin/sudo
```

How to fix it:

Boot a CD, DVD or USB key having a live distribution on it, mount your / file system and fix `sudo` permissions, and any other that might have been tampered. For example, here is a list of some files having the `s` bit set on my machine :

```
$ find /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin -perm /u=s
/bin/mount
/bin/ping6
/bin/fusermount
/bin/ping
/bin/umount
/bin/su
/sbin/mount.cifs
/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private
/usr/bin/sudo
/usr/bin/chsh
/usr/bin/gpasswd
/usr/bin/mtr
/usr/bin/lppasswd
/usr/bin/traceroute6.iputils
/usr/bin/X
/usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/newgrp
/usr/bin/pkexec
/usr/bin/chfn
/usr/sbin/uuidd
/usr/sbin/pppd
/usr/sbin/pppoe
```

Comment: I found the problem. I have copied the OS files from client pc to server pc. I have to change permission to one file so, by mistake i I changed the permissions(chmod 777 *)after exiting from root.then in got this problem.how to fix this?

Comment: Answer updated to add the "how to fix" part.